# Why python appends script dir differently in windows and linux to pythonpath?

Tags: python, linux, windows, pythonpath

I've got this structure:

test dir:

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── nested
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

Then i'm running script (python2.7) like this:

```
~/tmp/test$./nested/test.py
```

test.py:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

and got this on linux:

```
['/home/xliivdeb/tmp/test/nested', '/home/xliivdeb/tmp/test', ..]
```

and this on windows xp:

```
['E:\\tmp\\test\\nested', 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg', ..]
```

The diff is this:

On linux appended are:

- script dir ('/home/xliivdeb/tmp/test/nested') AND
- current dir ('/home/xliivdeb/tmp/test')

on windows appended is only:

- script dir ('E:\tmp\test\nested')

Why? How to deal with it? Do I have to append it manually if windows?

Comment: There is no guarantee I can see in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.path) the current directory will be in the path.

Comment: Ok, the docs says it appends only script's dir. So why linux additionally appends current dir? However i need solution.
What do You propose? :)

Comment: Well, the first question is why do you *need* the current directory to be in the path? It sounds like a bad idea to me. As to why your setup does (I wouldn't be so quick to say that this is the case in all situations under Linux - it's not the case under OS X for me, I'd like to hear another person check), that's something I don't really know. Are you sure that directory isn't just in your path normally?

Comment: I'm sure it's not in path noramally, i've just check it.
I'm doing that because, i've got a package and i'd like to run a module (because it includes some sort of test in "if name == '__main__' idiom) of the package. The module has package imports (so i need current dir appended to allow package imports works). It's hard to explain in the case from above.